# Perl chomp does not remove all the newlines

Tags: perl, newline, chomp

I have code like:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
open(IO,"<source.html");
my $variable = do {local $/; <IO>};
chomp($variable);
print $variable;
```

However when I print it, it still has newlines?

Comment: Next time ask yourself if you really think that a 10 year old feature of a mainstream language is really broken or if you're just using it wrong.

Comment: [`select` isn't broken](http://www.google.com/search?q=select+isn%27t+broken)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It removes the *last* newline.

Since you're slurping in the whole file, you're going to have to do a regex substitution to get rid of them:

```
$variable =~ s/\n//g;
```

Answer (score 7):

Chomp only removes a newline (actually, the current value of `$/`, but that's a newline in your case) from the end of the string.  To remove all newlines, do:

```
$variable =~ y/\n//d;
```

Answer (score 2):

Or you can `chomp` each line as you read it in:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

open my $io, '<', 'source.html';
my $chomped_text = join '', map {chomp(my $line = $_); $line} <$io>;

print $chomped_text;
```